# Self executing arrow functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am wondering how I syntactically change this self-executing exported function:

```
export default (() => ({
  get items() {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
      return { message: 'this is testing' };
    } else {
      return { message: 'this is not testing' };
    }
  },
}))();
```

Into something that uses ES6 arrow functions and the exported statement at the end (my best, incorrect guess):

```
const items = (() => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
    return { API_AUTHORITY: 'this is testing' };
  } else {
    return { API_AUTHORITY: 'this is not testing' };
  }
})();

export default items;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your first block of code looks to be exporting an object which has one property, `items`, which is a getter. Why not just export the plain object instead? (You're also already using an arrow function in the first code)

Comment: @CertainPerformance, please see the updated question.

Comment: Why not just set items and export it: `const items = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') ? { API_AUTHORITY: 'this is testing' }: { API_AUTHORITY: 'this is not testing' };` Will `NODE_ENV` change during runtime?

Comment: Or even `export default { API_AUTHORITY: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ? 'this is testing' : 'this is not testing' }` ???

Comment: Yes even better @Li357.

Answer (score 1):

The IIFE is not needed - simply export the object instead:

```
const obj = {
  get items() {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
      return { message: "this is testing" };
    } else {
      return { message: "this is not testing" };
    }
  }
};
export default obj;
```

If you really want a function, then define it one one line, and then you can execute it while exporting, though the intent isn't so clear:

```
const fn = () => ({
  get items() {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
      return { message: "this is testing" };
    } else {
      return { message: "this is not testing" };
    }
  }
});
export default fn();
```

or

```
const fn = // same as above
// ...
const obj = fn();
export default obj;
```

Comment: Or just `export default { items: { message: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ? 'this is testing' : 'this is not testing' } }`?

Answer (score 0):

@Li357 provided the answer in the comments; the function is unnecessary:

```
export default { items: { message: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ? 'this is testing' : 'this is not testing' } }
```